# How to make colorbox inline images, created withing colorbox tigger in view, open next image onclick

Tags: jquery, triggers, switch-statement, colorbox

I've created some gallery in view, using colorbox trigger, which includes image, title, rate it button. Everything working, and image is link to a node. I want i work default for colorbox image galery, so that when I click image it will open next image in gallery. I'm absolutely stuck, i've been searching inet for a 3 days, and didn't find anything. I tried to do a clickable image inside colorbox overlay, which will switch to next gallery page and tried different variations of code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/libraries/colorbox/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#nextlink").click(function() {
   $.colorbox.next();
   });
 });
```

and nothing happens, when i'm clicking nextlink. Though prev and next buttong works just as i want, i didn't succeded in coping their code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that your event handler is firing?  Also, if this is coming from an anchor element that has an href attribute, you'll have to handle the default behavior.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#nextlink").click(function(e) {
       $.colorbox.next();
       e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

Does your '#nextlink' exist in the document at the time you try to assign an event handler to it?  If not, you should use a live event (or update your version of jQuery and use the newer methods for handling event delegation).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#nextlink").live('click', function(e) {
       $.colorbox.next();
       e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```